# How to import JSON object into Processing file for webpage?

Tags: python, arrays, json, flask, processing

I created a Flask project. In one of the routes, I create a colormap palette and save these colours in RGB to a list. This list is stored in a variable in app.py. I need to pass the values of this list to my .pde file as the colours of my Processing sketch depend on the values in the list. Basically, I want each loop through my Processing sketch to pull a colour from the list, starting at index[0] and then moving up. This list is not static as the value of its parameters will change based on the user. I have tried some methods of setting the variable to a template variable that is then passed to .pde from an html file, but this just doesn't work. The alternative method I think will be more promising is saving the variable values to a JSON array in a separate JSON file. And then I need to access this JSON object from .pde and set it to a variable I can use for the fill() method in Processing. I have no idea how to load the JSON data! The load method I found online doesn't seem to apply for webpages as it's not JavaScript-compatible.

Here is the route in app.py:

```
@app.route('/processor')
def processor():
    palette = Cubehelix.make(start=0.3, rotation=-0.5, n=10)
    particleArray = palette.colors
    with open("particleArray.json", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(particleArray, f)
    with open("particleArray.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return render_template('a.html')
```

This is a.html that is being rendered by the above route:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Processing Sketch</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/processing.js/1.4.8/processing.min.js"></script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="{{url_for('static', filename= 'myProgram.pde')}}"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is myProgram.pde where my Processing sketch is store:

```
JSONObject json;

int dim; 

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  dim = width/2;
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
}


void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int x = 0; x <= width; x+=dim) {
    filter(BLUR,4);
    drawGradient(x/width, height);
  } 
}

void drawGradient(float x, float y) {
  int radius = dim*2;
  float a= 0;
  values= loadJSONArray("C:\Users\Me\ProjectName\myapp\particleArray.json");
  int h= 0;
  int len= values.size();
  float angle= radians(30+a);
  for (int r = radius; r > 0; --r) {
    rotate(radians(angle));
    int[] help= values.getInt(h);
    fill(help[0],help[1],help[2]);
    ellipse(x, y, r+30, r);
    a+=10;
    h++;
    if (h >= len) {
      h=0;
    }
  }
}
```

This together renders the Processing canvas but it's just black. Nothing is being drawn. I thought maybe I should try to write it in p5.js way because perhaps the loadJSONArray is not a thing for Javascript and wrote this version of the Processing sketch as tester.pde (and changed the html file to point to this file). This just renders a blank page. No canvas, nothing.

````
let particleArray;

function preload() {
  particleArray = loadJSON('C:\Users\Me\ProjectName\myapp\particleArray.json');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (let x = 0; x <= width; x += dim) {
    filter(BLUR, 4);
    drawGradient(x / width, height);
  }
}

function drawGradient(x, y) {
  let radius = dim * 2;
  let a = 0;
  let h = 0;
  let len = particleArray.length;
  let angle = radians(30 + a);
  for (let r = radius; r > 0; --r) {
    rotate(radians(angle));
    let help = particleArray[h];
    fill(help[0], help[1], help[2]);
    ellipse(x * width, y, r + 30, r);
    a += 10;
    h++;
    if (h >= len) {
      h = 0;
    }
  }
}```
````